# scala inheritence from java initialisation issue

Tags: java, scala

Say I have the following class in java:

```
class A
{
        public A()
        {
                init();
        }

        void init()
        {
                System.out.println("A:init()");
        }
}
```

And then I inherit from it in scala as follows:

```
class B extends A {

        var x = 3

        override def init(): Unit = println("init: x = " + x)
}
```

When I construct an instance of B the value for x in my init override will not be 3 of course as it won't have yet been initialised at that stage. If I cannot change the java class can someone recommend the best approach here to insure my class fields have been initialised when init() is called.

Thanks

Des

Comment: set the value in your init method?

Comment: Do you really need a _var_, or will a _val_ do?

Answer (score 0):

You can put that variable into a companion object and then just do

`override def init(): Unit = println("init: x = " + B.x)`

where `B` is declared like that:

```
object B {
  val x = 3
}
```

You also can define/initialize `x` inside `init()`.

Comment: -1?  If x really needs to be a _var_, not a val, as was described, then putting it in a companion object probably won't work, since it probably needs to be per-instance.

Comment: Well, since `x` should be initialized *before* class instantiation, I assume that one can't define/initialize `x` the other way. Also, there is a workaround for that - you can do it like that:`def x = 3`, so you can get some initial value, and then, if there is really need for x to be mutated, just have another variable to store. But,  as for now, I assume that the main idea of OP is to get some *initial* value, and that's achieved via `object` singleton.

Comment: Correct Ed, I want x to be mutable but with an initial value. I probably should have had init() modify x in the above example to be more clear. In java this would not be an issue as the constructor would be called AFTER member variable initialisation. I was just hoping there was as neat away of achieving this in scala.